# Clipping masks with gradient map in CSS

Tags: html, css, photoshop, mask, clipping

Is there any way to create such an experience with the CSS?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kid0skuifhr5jj/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-19%20at%2017.33.16.png?dl=0

There is a clipping mask with the gradient map (from #663897 to #02ccfe) applied to an image.

I've tried to create an overlay with the gradient background, but it's different. I'm totally lost, can't find anything on the internet. :(

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you mean "clipping mask" and not "blend mode? Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/tonuauz4/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #02ccfe 0%, #663897 100%), url(http://placekitten.com/g/500/300);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #02ccfe 0%, #663897 100%), url(http://placekitten.com/g/500/300);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #02ccfe 0%, #663897 100%), url(http://placekitten.com/g/500/300);
  background-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

h1 {
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <h1>
    Lorem Ipsum
  </h1>
</div>
```

Be aware that this will not work in Internet Explorer ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode))

Comment: It is not exactly what I'm looking for. I'll show one more picture.

http://tinyurl.com/hkw9dwz As you see, the dark parts of the original image are more purple while the lighter colors are more blueish.

Here is the photo of the Photoshop layers
http://tinyurl.com/z3ac98h

I'm not a Photoshop pro, I might be wrong, but there are white layer mask and gradient map. Not the blending mode.

Comment: The clipping  mask in your image is having no effect on the colour of the output. It is "clipping" or "cropping" the image to a shape specified in the bottom layer. The top layer is an adjustment layer that is probably changing the colour somehow. If you look above the layers you will see the blend mode dropdown (http://i.stack.imgur.com/PHhnM.png) which is probably set to something like "screen" or "hard-light" - this is the effect that I am trying to simulate above. If the colours aren't quite right, adjust them. I've shown you the technique. You now need to tweak it to suit your needs.

Comment: There are no blending modes. Seems that it can't be done in CSS. Thank you, for answer!